# Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0) on React Native Dialogflow Project

Tags: windows, react-native, visual-studio-code, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am a newbie and want to learn react native by building a project. I follow this tutorial how to build chatbot using React Native and Dialogflow:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXPp6t7yflA&t=77s

I am using VS Code on Windows 10. When I type: **npx react-native run-android** the emulator start but the warnings came out:

1. new NativeEventEmitter() was called with a non-null argument without
   the requeired 'addListener' method
2. new NativeEventEmitter() was called with a non-null argument without
   the requeired 'removeListener' method

[image: When the chatbot run at the first time]

When I type a message there is a warning too and the chatbot doesn't reply a text:
**Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0):**

[image: After sent a message]

[image: Detai/ error after sent a message]

Here is the code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {Dialogflow_V2} from 'react-native-dialogflow';
import {GiftedChat} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import {dialogflowConfig} from './env';

const botAvatar = require('./assets/images/mascot.png');

const BOT = {
  _id: 2,
  name: 'Abot',
  avatar: botAvatar
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    messages: [{_id: 2, text: 'My name is Abot. What can I do for you?', createdAt: new Date(), user: BOT},{_id: 1, text: 'Hello', createdAt: new Date(), user: BOT}],
    id: 1,
    name: '',
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    Dialogflow_V2.setConfiguration(
      dialogflowConfig.client_email,
      dialogflowConfig.private_key,
      Dialogflow_V2.LANG_ENGLISH_US,
      dialogflowConfig.project_id,
    );
  }

  handleGoogleResponse(result){
    let text = result.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].
    text.text[0];

    this.sendBotResponse(text);
  }

  sendBotResponse(text){
    let msg = {
      _id: this.state.messages.length + 1,
      text,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      user: BOT
    }

    this.setState((previouseState) => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previouseState.
        messages, [msg]),
    }));
  }

  onSend(messages = []) {
    this.setState((previouseState) => ({
      messages: GiftedChat.append(previouseState.
        messages,messages)
    }))
  

  let message = messages[0].text;

  Dialogflow_V2.requestQuery(
    message,
    (result) => this.handleGoogleResponse(result),
    (error) => console.log(error)
  )
}

onQuickReply(quickReply) {
  this.setState((previouseState) => ({
    messages: GiftedChat.append(previouseState.
      messages,quickReply)
  }))


let message = quickReply[0].value;

Dialogflow_V2.requestQuery(
  message,
  (result) => this.handleGoogleResponse(result),
  (error) => console.log(error)
)
}

  render() {
    return (
     <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
       <GiftedChat messages={this.state.messages}
       onSend={(message) => this.onSend(message)}
       onQuickReply={(quickReply) => this.onQuickReply(quickReply)}
       user={{_id: 1}}
       />
     </View>
    )
   
  }
  

}

export default App;
```

Please help, how to fix this issues, so I can continue my learning. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by me:

- downgrade the React Native to 0.64.1
- reinstall the project again from the beginning following the
  documentation react-native-gifted-chat and react-native-dialogflow.

Thanks.